# Marionettte Memory usage

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am still very new to front end web development so I am wetting my beak to designing an APP with Backbone+Marionette.

> Poor question but perhaps someone can enlighten me to the issue I am
>   pondering on. I know this memory conservation will be an issue on the
>   mobiles- so any insight?

My questions is as follows. If I am building a site that is very highly data intensive (viewing images, browsing profiles, etc etc). How important is the conservation of memory on the client. I am thinking that I should be formatting particular models when their views are inactive --is this a rational course of action.

Ex: 
Client navigates to /pics
pics model  fetches data and then the view displays the data.
*After which the model will be cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kris,

I am not 100% sure what your issue is however I suspect you are thinking about the lifecycle of your models.

I think that you should just think about the scope of your models and collections.

Lets say you have a controller, that has set up a region and shows a view in that region.

If the view that is shown loaded the models within the view's scope, then when the controller shows a different view in the same region Marionette will automatically close the previous view and its models will be garbage collected.

If it was your controller that loaded up the model and passed it to the view then you will need to make sure you dispose of the reference to the model in the controller to allow for garbage collection.

Comment: That was the exact answer I was looking for. THNX!